# CSS3 Navigation Menu

Tags: css

I am unable to fix these 2 issues for my menu. Using Chrome.

1. The little left pointer arrow for the sub-sub-menu(Men,Women/Children) hides behind the list.
   [image]

This is the desired output:

[image]

2. Ideally, the sub menus should appear only when hovered on the parent menu. 
   But here, they appear even when hovered a littl away too. You can see this if you place the cursor, at about 10 px right below 'portfolio' or 20 px below 'links'

   http://jsfiddle.net/mdB9z/

   ```
   nav ul li > ul li > ul:before
    {
     content:"";
      border-style:solid;
      border-width:0 9px 9px 9px;
     border-color:transparent transparent #2c3e50 transparent;
     width:0;
     height:0;
     position:absolute;
     left:0;
     top:15px;
     -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for

**1.) Arrows**

It seems to be a result of the arrow element being absolutely positioned. Do you consider relative positioning an issue? Because if not, you could use that - and it works as long as you also apply a `z-index` (such as 1).

```
nav ul li > ul li > ul:before {
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    top:15px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

**2.) Visibility**

You have to hide the element if you don't want it to trigger `:hover` on mouseover. Using `display:block` to `display:none` or vice-verse cancels out or rather skips CSS3 transitions, so use `visibility:visible` to `visiblity:hidden` instead.

```
nav ul li > ul {
    visibility: hidden;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/mdB9z/1/).

Is this what you tried to achieve?

Comment: Thank you. The second problems solved. But the first one isnt. If you can see, the arrow now points to the top instead of right and also, it is inside the ul .I have updated the question with the desired output.

Comment: It seems that the transforms are not applied to these pseudo-elements. Is it an option for you to add the arrow element to the markup instead (as a DIV) and then apply your styles to that directly? That should work.

Comment: The transform does apply when I changed position back to absolute. I have no idea how I would go with div.

Comment: You are using `ul:before` but you could also just add a DIV before the UL, give it a classname, and refer to that class in the CSS code.

Comment: Actually it seems ok with `position:absolute'. See http://jsfiddle.net/mdB9z/4/ - the transforms work well here.

Comment: Yes Exactly They Do. Could you please suggest how I proceed with the div method. ..<li><div class="divUl"></div><ul>...</ul>...and in css..would it be nav ul li > ul li > divUl:before ??

Comment: Not entirely. You don't need `:before` anymore. But if you want to refer to `<div class="divUI"></div>` your CSS declaration must look like this: `nav ul li > ul li > .divUI`. Please beware that using `>` in your CSS declaration will limit the declaration to immediate child nodes. So that means `.divUI` must be a direct child of the last `li`.